# How to detect credit cards harvested from memory?

Tags: linux, php, apache, nginx

Had a chat recently with PCI compliance specialist and got to realize there is a way to steal raw data from Apache / Nginx memory e.g. credit cards. It's called "harvesting" and becomes pretty common.

Let's say somebody hacked in through a file upload functionality and gained access. What would be the way to detect it if he managed to harvest anything or is still harvesting, assuming he could clean up/change logs and mods after himself?

Answer (score 4):

Once an attacker gains control of a computer, you cannot trust anything on that computer; inspecting the computer cannot tell you with certainty what happened or is happening.

Your best bet is to watch for the attacker's efforts to get data off of your network and onto a computer under his control.  Monitor outgoing connections at the firewall to see if there are any going to unusual locations; inspect outgoing data to see if it contains anything that looks like sensitive data.

You can also attempt to spot the attack by having the server send its log messages to a secure logging server and inspecting for things that look like an attack.  However, 1) there will be a lot of false positives, 2) a successful attack may not create a log entry, and 3) once the attack succeeds, further log entries cannot be trusted.  Don't expect this to be useful except possibly for post-incident analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Mark's answer. Independent data loss protection services and deep monitoring services that run in the shadows of your network are the only realistic way to catch the kind of extended attacks that we are currently experiencing. Bearing in mind that currently, the average time to discovery is the best part of a year and that discovery usually happens from the outside, this is a major issue.

However, better still is not to allow sensitive data onto your system at all!

Better to hand this piece of specialist processing to a specialist function. That could be run by yourselves or by a third party.

If you have to take the details using your own website, you could pre-encrypt the details client-side and pass them straight through to a separate store, have a "grabber" within your secure network that takes entries out of the temporary store and processes them in a more secure environment than your web server (which will be in a DMZ or worse, a cloud hosting environment).

Handing the whole problem to a specialist 3rd party (PayPal, Globalpay, etc) is even easier since they take all the pain and risk in exchange for a small overhead cost.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Mark and Julian's answers here....

As a consumer I'm much more comfortable buying stuff from a site which uses a recognizable payment processor than one which wants my card details.

But to get back to the question, a counter-measure which is effective for all sorts of scenarios is to seed your data with honeypots (honey tokens).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to mitigate these kinds of problems, you might be interested in running your web server as a non-root user inside of a [Docker](https://docker.io) container or LXC container.

This mitigates the threat in the way that Docker works. Docker containers are isolated Linux environments that, for all intensive purposes, are self-contained operating systems. They are incredibly lightweight, however, and are not the same as virtualization in any way.

Running your webserver inside of a Docker container as a non-root user means that *at best* an attacker can only get access to the Docker container's memory and never the host machine's memory, provided that Docker and LXC has been implemented properly (and LXC support in the kernel's been around for quite a while).

By using Docker's networking support, you can then "expose" the web server to your own local port 80/443, which basically uses port-forwarding to forward all traffic on those ports to select ports on the Docker container (ie 8080 and 8443, because you can't bind to 80 and 443 as a non-root user).

For the end-user, in effect nothing has changed. All traffic is forwarded to a real webserver running in a LXC container. However, if an attacker succeeds in gaining remote code execution, he will be incredibly limited in what he'll be able to do (again, if Docker and LXC have been implemented properly).